# Using javascript document object after window.location page load

Tags: javascript, location, window, document, window.location

I am trying to load an url and then fill the form immediately after it is loaded.

Here is what i tried:

```
javascript:{
           window.location="https://www.facebook.com/?stype=lo&jlou=AffoWJuaYAs9TGVJCTVUruYGqXCC7cIroybz901ZQrGraXOJs3qGWGifWAvYxyKyOO8oVYA2yzomzxeVB19f4AB2aE8pEbsnomjJFVxzxe5Waw&smuh=28282&lh=Ac8QfKf9iqWPFNui";
   window.onload=function() {
       document.getElementById("email").value="xxxxxxxxxxx";
       document.getElementById("pass").value="xxxxxxxxxx";
       document.getElementById("u_0_l").click();
   }}void(0);
```

then added it as a bookmarklet. But clicking on it only loads the url and stops, does not set the value on load. Why is the document object not pointing to the currently

Comment: When you will use `window.location` handle will go to other page.

Comment: As soon as you set window.location none of the remaining code will run, the new page will load instead Don't you need to submit this form...and how are you planning to submit it? Not at all clear what you are trying to achieve. Broken code is not a good substitute for a proper explanation of the full process flow expected

Comment: Keep in mind too that using a bookmarklet like that means you are storing your password in plain text. Better to use a password manager like 1Password / Lastpass / Keepass.

Comment: 1. Load the home page url
2. Fill in the user name password from
3. Get the login button clicked and end up logging in to the Facebook home page.
But all of the three steps should be completed in One click ok a javascript bookmarklet.  I don't to do this in two clicks, which i am currently doing. @charlietfl

Comment: Also my main purpose is an automation for my day to day office work, not to only just logging in to the Facebook, i gave this example just to explain the scenario simply. @Dymos